# can't import pyd file from scipy

Tags: python, python-2.7, numpy, scipy

trying to import scipy.interpolate but it can’t import _fblas.pyd. It keeps throwing the following error

```
File "C:\cygwin64\lib\python2.7\site-packages\scipy/linalg/blas.py", line 155, in <module>    
    from scipy.linalg import _fblas
ImportError: cannot import name _fblas
```

My online research suggested that this is because I had the wrong version of numpy installed, and I need to install numpy+mkl. So I uninstalled the version I had and pip installed numpy 1.10.4, which includes mkl.

This did not fix the original problem with _flbas.pyd.

I would reinstall scipy but I can't remember where I got the version I have, and when I pip install scipy 0.17.1.tar.gz it throws an error saying that it has no blas resources, which are necessary. I've also tried to download it from here: https://github.com/scipy/scipy/releases, but they don't include _fblas.pyd in the first place.

I’m not sure where to go from here. I'm not even entirely sure why it won't import the _fblas.pyd file.

Comment: Are you using an alternative implementation of python?

Comment: I'm using python 2.7.11, from python.org

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This looks like you tried to *manually* comply to your needed packages. Even though I take my hat off at your effort, keep in mind that this is not an simple task at all.

I might also add that this kind of work is not meant for a developer ("the person who writes the code"), but a full time maintainer. Specially with your particular Cygwin environment

So, what *can* you do? Alternatively, you can use one of [Continuum's mkl-ready python-and-many-tools-including-mkl+scipy distribution](https://www.continuum.io/blog/developer-blog/anaconda-25-release-now-mkl-optimizations) or [Enthought's Canopy](https://www.enthought.com/products/canopy/). Hopefully, this will avoid you lots of hours of staring at the screen wondering what's wrong

Comment: Just want to make clear that I am not affiliated to Continuum. Right now, I don't know of other MKL ready Python distribution. Write a comment if you know of other.

Comment: That's pretty much exactly what I ended up doing, but I'm using Canopy. It works now. Thank you.

Comment: Adding canopy to the answer 